# data saving best convention for multi skills and language

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I am confuse about best practice to save 2 fields data for example :

1 user can have multiple languages like  `English , Arabic , French` etc
**and**
1 user can have multiple skills  like  `adobe , databases , python , C`  etc

so what is best way to save , I was saving thinking to save json but I have to query on it later so can't 2ndly I was thinking to create a separate  table for languages and separate table for skills  etc . but seems It will create overhead ? Kindly suggest what is best in this case

Comment: Separate normalized tables with foreign keys. What overhead do you think it will have, and why do you think that overhead is more than the overhead of JSON?

Comment: @Charlieface a idea just came in my  mind to create a ManyToManyField in User table and then skill table . is this good ? as of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963852/create-multivalued-field-for-storing-user-skill-set-in-user-profile-django

Comment: No, you want the following tables `User` `Langauge` `Skill` and these two many:many join tables `UserLanguage` `UserSkill`

Comment: @Charlieface .  For example  this will be my final design  `1. User -> ManyToManyField -> SkillEndorsment`  , 2 .  `User -> ManyToManyField -> LanguageEndorsment`  right ?

Comment: Not sure why you keep saying `ManyToManyField`, you want a completely separate table, containing `(UserId, SkillId)` as a composite primary key

Comment: @Charlieface I mean many to many relation . Just wanted to confirm what is best in this case many to many or one to many .